# Unable to load Swift runtime library (image not found)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, osx-yosemite

I updated one of my core frameworks to use Swift as an experiment. It builds fine, the compatibility header has the Swift classes available to the Objective-C classes that depend on them, and everything compiles fine.

However, when launching the application (base SDK and deployment target `OS X 10.10`) it crashes immediately with:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Craig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacApp-dxcgahgplwpbjedqnembegifbowj/Build/Products/Debug/Fluffy.framework/Versions/A/Fluffy
  Reason: image not found
```

Note that `MacApp` is the application I'm launching, and it uses the `Fluffy` framework containing Swift code.

The `Fluffy` project has its `Runpath Search Paths` set to:

`@executable_path/Frameworks`

But I have *also tried it blank*. I have tried restarting Xcode, to no avail. Using Yosemite 14A298i and Xcode beta 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Runpath Search Paths` for my framework (`Fluffy`) containing the Swift code needed to be updated. It originally contained:

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/../Frameworks
```

But after creating a sample Swift project and comparing the build settings, Xcode was adding:

`@loader_path/Frameworks`

To the newly-created project. This was missing from my existing framework project. Adding it so the `Runpath Search Paths` contained these values solved the problem:

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/../Frameworks
@loader_path/Frameworks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you faced Library not loaded error in run time you should add those libraries in Embedded Binary.

**Step 01 :-**

Make sure that library is in the current project Navigation. If not Drag and drop library in to your project navigation.

**Step 02 :-**

Click on project > General > Embedded Binary > Add library which showed in your error. In this case you should add libswift_stdlib_core.

[image]